# $\ker(T) \subseteq\ker(S)$ implies the exist some $H$ s.t. $H\circ T=S$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V,W$ be vector spaces with finite dimension. Let $T,S:V\rightarrow W$ be linear transformations such that $\ker(T)\subseteq \ker(S)$. Prove that there exists a linear transformation $H:W\rightarrow W$ such  that $H\circ T=S$.

My approach was to take a basis $\{v_{1},...,v_{k}\}$ of $\ker(T)$, expanding it to $\{v_{1},...,v_{k},v_{k+1},..,{v_{m}}\}$, a basis of $\ker(S)$, and then expanding it to $\{v_{1},...,v_{n}\}$ a basis for $V$ (assuming $\dim V=n$).

I tried to think how to construct $H$, but couldn't think of a way.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the family of vectors $(T(v_{k+1}),\ldots, T(v_n))$ is linearly independent in $W$ (why?) and we complete it on $(T(v_{k+1}),\ldots, T(v_n),z_1,\ldots,z_p)$ a basis for $W$. Now define $H$ in this manner:

$$H(T(v_i))=0,\; i=k+1,\ldots,m$$
and
$$H(T(v_i))=S(v_i),\; i=m+1,\ldots,n$$
and 
$$H(T(z_i))=0,\; i=1,\ldots,p$$
so $H\circ T$ and $S$ are equal since they are equal on a basis.

Answer (score 1):

You can just say that $H$ is defined by the property $H(Tx) = Sx$ for all $x$ in the image of $T$, and extend it linearly defining $H$ to be anything in some basis for $\ker T$. Then we have to check that $H$ is well-defined, and this is where $\ker T \subset \ker S$ comes into play. If $x = y$ are in $V$, then $Tx = Ty$, and so $T(x-y) = 0$. So $x-y \in \ker T \subset \ker S$, and $S(x-y) = 0$ gives us $Sx = Sy$, I mean, $H(Tx) = H(Ty)$. So $H$ is well-defined. Also, if $T$ is onto, this $H$ is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a basis of $V$ which starts with a basis $t_{1}, \dots, t_{a}$ of $\ker(T)$, is then extended to a basis $t_{1}, \dots, t_{a}, s_{1}, \dots, s_{b}$ of $\ker(S)$, and finally is extended to a basis $t_{1}, \dots, t_{a}, s_{1}, \dots, s_{b}, v_{1}, \dots, v_{c}$ of $V$.

Clearly
$$T(s_{1}), \dots, T(s_{b}), T(v_{1}), \dots, T(v_{c})\tag{bim}$$
is a basis for the image $T(V)$ of $T$.

Extend (bim) to a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $W$. Define $H$ by
$$H(T(s_{1})) =  \dots = H(T(s_{b})) = 0,\\ H(T(v_{1})) = S(v_{1}), \dots, H(T(v_{c})) = S(v_{c}),$$
and assigning arbitrary values to $H$ on the remaining elements of $\mathcal{B}$.